# Fullcalendar translate for next prev customButtons using locale file

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar with customized buttons for prev, next, today in the toolbar, but i am facing the problem that i need an automatic translation as the other buttons do.

I use the locales-all.js file to translate these default buttons, when i don't define next, prev, today in customButtons, they are automatically translated depending on the browser language, but when i define them in customButtons, it no longer works. Is there any way to solve this?

```
headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,today,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
},
customButtons: {
next: {
    text: 'next', <<< need automatic translation, better if use locales-all.js
    click: function() {
    }
},
prev: {
    text: 'prev', <<< same
    click: function() {
    }
},
today: {
    text: 'today', <<< same
    click: function() {}
}
```

},